# Can I add a bind paste event on mousedown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bind, paste, onmousedown

I want to catch the paste event with right Click and Paste selection on a textarea. What I did is:

```
$(window).bind('paste', function(event) {                  
    pasteText();  
    return false;              
 });
```

and it works ok. So when the Paste is clicked a small popup window is shown. What I want is to make this popup window shown on mousedown event. I mean when I click the Paste (mousedown) then I want to see the popup.
Is this possible to happen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch the mousedown event *on the context menu* (as one could prevent save as, view source, etc functions)...so the browsers really don't fire an event there.

Comment: So do you have any idea of how can I do something like this, or is something I just can't do?

Comment: @novellino - It's not something you can do...there's just no event there (imagine the popup interrupting your paste, see how annoying it could be?)  You could store the value *before* the `paste` event, and revert it if needed, would that accomplish what you're after?

Comment: Ok that would be perfect but the problem is I can not store my value before the paste somewhere. I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: @novellino - just store the `.val()` result whenever it changes, e.g. a `.change()` handler...use that value for that it was previously, before the paste event.